# Hp Proliant DL120 G7 won't show ORCA

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

I have on old server, HP Proliant DL120 G7. I configured it with 4 500GB Hard Disk in RAID 10.
With this configuration I was able to enter in ORCA setup and the hard drives where connected.
Then I changed the drives to 4 1TB Hard Disk. I wasn't able to make the server read a bootable usb to install Esx6 and taken by disconfort I restored default setting in the bios.
Now it won't read the new hard drives and won't show the option to enter ORCA pressing F8.

The error after Smart Array tools searching for drives is: *"drives array not configured"*

I searched for SmartArray P410 drivers, but I can't find it anywhere. I have the link in the documentation, but it's not available anymore.
In your opinion it's driver problem? Or maybe there is one option in BIOS that let me enable the smart array?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the Smart Array P400 was broken. I found another one in my company storage, changed it and magically all started working again. ORCA only show when at least one Hard Disk is found.